# Running image upload code in Apache

Tags: php, jquery, apache, wamp

I tried a code sample for uploading image to server using JQuery AJAX and PHP with WAMP server. Will the same code work using Apache web server?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

WAMPServer **is Apache** and MYSQL and PHP all installed in a nice easy bundle.

So nice and easy you obviously did not even look at what you had installed.